# React Material-ui Datepicker / Timepicker OnChange Event callback function encapsulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, material-ui

I'm fairly new to React and I'm using [Material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) as an additional UI dependency. I have some repetition in my code that is a little tricky to remove since I think I'm restricted by a Material-ui component's implementation.

Here's my class that I need help with re-organizing

```
...other imports...
import EntryForm from './entryform';
export default class TimeSheet extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.state = {
        entry: {
            date: null,
            startTime: null,
            endTime: null,
        },
        list: []
    };

    // ... Class method bindings here ...
}


// ------- METHODS I WOULD LIKE TO CONSOLIDATE -----
dateChanged(event, date) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        entry: { ...prevState.entry, date: new Date(date) }
    }));
}

startChanged(event, date) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        entry: { ...prevState.entry, startTime: new Date(date) }
    }));
}

endChanged(event, date) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        entry: { ...prevState.entry, endTime: new Date(date) }
    }));
}
// ------- METHODS I WOULD LIKE TO CONSOLIDATE -----

saveTimeSheetEntry(event) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        list: prevState.list.concat([{
            ...prevState.entry
        }])
    }));
}

render() {
    return (
       ...some stuff

            <EntryForm
                dateChanged={this.dateChanged}
                startChanged={this.startChanged}
                endChanged={this.endChanged}
                date={this.state.entry.date}
                startTime={this.state.entry.startTime}
                endTime={this.state.entry.endTime}
                save={this.saveEntry}
            />

        ...other stuff
    )
}
}
```

**EDIT**

`./EntryForm` Component

```
const EntryForm = (props) => (
    <Paper style={paperStyle} zDepth={1}>
        <DatePicker onChange={props.dateChanged} value={props.date} hintText="Timesheet Date" />
        <TimePicker onChange={props.startChanged} value={props.startTime} hintText="Start Time" />
        <TimePicker onChange={props.endChanged} value={props.endTime} hintText="End Time" />
        <FlatButton onClick={props.save} label="Save" backgroundColor="#18cbce" fullWidth={true} />
    </Paper>
);
```

As you can see, there are 3 methods that I would like to try to consolidate into a single method. `dateChanged` `startChanged` and `endChanged` all of these methods are plugged into material-ui's `Datepicker/Timepicker` `onChange` prop. Normally I would just do something like this

```
handleChange(event, date, stateItem) {
    this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        entry: { ...state.entry, [stateItem]: date }
    }));
}
```

But when I try it throws an error, probably because 
the Date/Time picker implementation looks like this.

```
<Timepicker onChange={props.startChange} ...otherProps />
```

[see the source code for this here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/TimePicker/TimePicker.js) check out line 149.

It's okay because the app is small, and it's just a basic time sheet entry. But it would become super unruly if I had to do this with many state objects.

Is there any solution that would prevent me from having 3 different touch points for such a similar operation?

p.s. sorry for ...spread abuse :)

Comment: `But when I try it throws an error` ( what error ?  )

Comment: `sorry for ...spread abuse` : you don't need to set the full state

Comment: could you explain what / when trigger:  `startChanged` and `endChanged`

Comment: also if you can add the code of  `./entryform'`  in the post ^^

Comment: Thanks I updated my answer, you get the error `date` is undefined because `onChange` only have one parameter `value` you are passing the second parameter ( undefined) ^^

Comment: see [example](https://github.com/react-component/time-picker/blob/master/examples/12hours.js#L16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## States updates are merged

> When you call setState(), React merges the object you provide into the current state.

You don't need to update the full state, react will update `independently` the given object, the rest will remain intact.

See: [States updates are merged](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged)

## Main handler

> there are 3 methods that I would like to try to consolidate into a single method

You only need  `category` and `date` ( no need for event ):

```
     handleChange(category, date) {
        this.setState(prevState => {

            // Get previous state
            const { entry } = prevState;

            // Set state: date | startTime | endTime
            entry[category] = date; 

            //Update state
            return { entry };
        });
     }
```

## Bind handler

To make work `this` and `setState` inside an inner component:

```
<EntryForm onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) } {...} />
```

## Using the handler

Just use `this.props.onChange` instead of `startChanged`, `endChanged`, `dateChanged`:

```
//dateChanged
this.props.onChange('date', date);

//startChanged
this.props.onChange('startTime', date);

//endChanged
this.props.onChange('endTime', date);
```

## Timepicker

> But when I try it throws an error, probably because the Date/Time picker implementation looks like this.

the `onChange` callback only pass one argument `value` (that's the date)

```
function onChange(value) {
  console.log(value && value.format(format));
}
```

Since you only need `date` you can override the implementation with an anonymous function 
 ( just wrap it inside another function ):

```
<Timepicker onChange={ date => { props.onChange('date', date ) } />
```

Comment: This is a really great answer. I did try something similar to this. But it was not nearly as clean. Unfortunately because I have to use the Timepicker's onChange like this  `<TimePicker  onChange={props.startChanged} value={props.startTime} hintText="Start Time" />` the error that is thrown is `'date' is not defined no-undef` I realized that I should have included this line in the original question from the beginning.

Comment: @Edwinj thanks I saw the docs,  so the callback should be `function(value)`

Comment: value is the date ^^

Comment: Your override method was very close! I had to add one more parameter because the first argument passed in is null for some reason. `<DatePicker name="date" onChange={ (noval, date) => { props.handleChange('date', date) } }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to comment yet. So here goes:

I don't think you can, since you need to distinguish between the states you want to set. If you consolidate these methods you would need a switch or an if or something which in my opinion is worse then this.

Comment: Yea I'm hard pressed to find another way too. Hence this question. If someone can't come up with something I'm probably going to make a feature request on the material-ui github.